# $L^2$ product of three functions two of which are orthogonal

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis

Let $f,g,h \in L^2(0,1) \cap L^\infty(0,1)$. Suppose that $f,g$ are orthogonal in $L^2$.
Is it true that $$\int_{0}^1 fgh \ dx = 0 \ ?$$ I would say yes because
$$|\int_{0}^1 fgh \ dx| \le \Vert h \Vert_\infty| \int_0^1 fg \ dx| = 0, $$
but I feel that I'm missing something

Answer (score 0):

I think it is false just choose $f(x)=1$ , $g(x)=1$ when $x\leq 1/2$ and $g(x)=-1$ when $x>1/2$ , so clearly they are orthogonal in $L^2$ and choosing $h=g$ or some other function would do the job

Answer (score 0):

The absolute values in your inequality are misplaced (outside the integral rather than inside). The version with absolute values outside the integral can be shown to be false with the functions
$$\begin{align}
f(x)&=1\\
g(x)&=\sin(2\pi x)\\
h(x)&=\sin(2\pi x)
\end{align}$$
as then $f$ and $g$ are orthogonal. Thus the RHS of the inequality is $0$, but the LHS is positive as it is an integral of a positive function over a set of positive measure.

This example is then a counterexample to your claim.